# Flink 1.4 AvroUtils error

Tags: java, apache-flink, avro, kryo

I try to submit a job on Flink 1.4 and getting the following exception.

Any idea how to solve the problem?

```
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$6.apply$mcV$sp(JobManager.scala:897)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$6.apply(JobManager.scala:840)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$6.apply(JobManager.scala:840)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:39)
at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:415)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/apache/flink/formats/avro/utils/AvroKryoSerializerUtils.addAvroGenericDataArrayRegistration(Ljava/util/LinkedHashMap;)V @23: invokespecial
  Reason:
Type 'org/apache/flink/api/java/typeutils/runtime/kryo/Serializers$SpecificInstanceCollectionSerializerForArrayList' (current frame, stack[7]) is not assignable to 'com/esotericsoftware/kryo/Serializer'
  Current Frame:
bci: @23
flags: { }
locals: { 'org/apache/flink/formats/avro/utils/AvroKryoSerializerUtils', 'java/util/LinkedHashMap' }
stack: { 'java/util/LinkedHashMap', 'java/lang/String', uninitialized 6, uninitialized 6, 'java/lang/Class', uninitialized 12, uninitialized 12, 'org/apache/flink/api/java/typeutils/runtime/kryo/Serializers$SpecificInstanceCollectionSerializerForArrayList' }
   Bytecode:
0x0000000: 2b12 05b6 000b bb00 0c59 1205 bb00 0d59
0x0000010: bb00 0659 b700 0eb7 000f b700 10b6 0011
0x0000020: 57b1                                   

at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)
at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.AvroUtils.getAvroUtils(AvroUtils.java:48)
at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.kryo.KryoSerializer.buildKryoRegistrations(KryoSerializer.java:481)
at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.kryo.KryoSerializer.<init>(KryoSerializer.java:119)
at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.GenericTypeInfo.createSerializer(GenericTypeInfo.java:90)
at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TupleTypeInfo.createSerializer(TupleTypeInfo.java:107)
at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TupleTypeInfo.createSerializer(TupleTypeInfo.java:52)
at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.ListTypeInfo.createSerializer(ListTypeInfo.java:102)
at org.apache.flink.api.common.state.StateDescriptor.initializeSerializerUnlessSet(StateDescriptor.java:253)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.DefaultOperatorStateBackend.getListState(DefaultOperatorStateBackend.java:520)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.DefaultOperatorStateBackend.getUnionListState(DefaultOperatorStateBackend.java:165)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.initializeState(FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.java:692)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.util.functions.StreamingFunctionUtils.tryRestoreFunction(StreamingFunctionUtils.java:178)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.util.functions.StreamingFunctionUtils.restoreFunctionState(StreamingFunctionUtils.java:160)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractUdfStreamOperator.initializeState(AbstractUdfStreamOperator.java:96)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator.initializeState(AbstractStreamOperator.java:259)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.initializeOperators(StreamTask.java:694)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.initializeState(StreamTask.java:682)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:253)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:718)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: currently preventing upgrade from 1.3.1 to 1.4

Comment: we have met the same error when upgrading to 1.4 from 1.3.2. We're still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

thanks to "toch" on previous answer - he gave me a direction for the solution

```
<exclude>com.esotericsoftware.kryo:kryo</exclude>
```

was already excluded in our `pom.xml`

I notice that `kryo-shaded` was included

I excluded by add to the pom

```
<exclude>com.esotericsoftware:kryo-shaded</exclude>
```

and it solve the problem

Answer (score 6):

It's a conflict between the Kryo lib into the job jar and the one already loaded in Flink.

Indeed, *Serializers$SpecificInstanceCollectionSerializerForArrayList* inherits from *com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Serializer* through *SpecificInstanceCollectionSerializer* and *CollectionSerializer*.
(see [Serializers.java](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-core/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/api/java/typeutils/runtime/kryo/Serializers.java#L182) in Flink and [CollectionSerializer.java](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo/blob/master/src/com/esotericsoftware/kryo/serializers/CollectionSerializer.java) in Kryo).

We fix it by excluding the Kryo lib from the job Jar. In Gradle build.gradle, it is done with (if you use ShadowJar plugin):

```
configurations {
  runtime.exclude module: 'kryo' , group: 'com.esotericsoftware.kryo'
}
```

In Maven pom.xml, it is done with (if you use shade plugin):

```
<exclude>com.esotericsoftware.kryo:kryo</exclude>
```

Comment: Where in the Maven pom file do you put the exclude exactly?